# Gift Message: "for learning" or "to learning"

Tags: expressions

I want to send a gift to someone. She loves learning. Which version of the following looks better/correct?

> To learning and knowledge!

Or

> For learning and knowledge!

Note that learning and knowledge is what we share in common.

Comment: Please provide more context. Specifically, tell us the sentence you want to use, containing the word "learning".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add to [@BellaSwan](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/201662/89027)'s answer the following:

- use "To" if you want the message to sound like "Cheers!";
- use "For if you want it to make like a statement without (great) emphasis.

I am not a master of composing greetings, but I would **move the focus** from "learning" to "she":

> **To** a great **learner** and her continued success!

or:

> **To** the most knowledgeable best **friend** / BFF!

or:

> **To** our friend, **for** ever increasing success!

Of course, you will adapt the text to the reality of your situation ;)

With a *small probability*, wishing somebody to learn may even transmit the wrong message, as if they really need to improve their knowledge / culture.

---

It just occurred to me (playing with the words in my head), that it is not going to be (very) wrong either way, using "to" or "for". You need to be more careful to the rest of the message.

---

Another point of view:

- use "To" to specify the person
- use "For" to specify the rest of the wish

Comment: Great idea to move the focus to her. What do you think of "To my friend and her devotion to learning?"

Comment: That is OK too. I you drop the "learning" part entirely, it will still not be bad. I assume that the gift is somehow related to learning (a book, a tool...). I really hope that there will be a gift NOT related to learning too (perfume, flowers, chocolate, gift certificate / bonus card... )

Answer (score 3):

**"To learning and knowledge!"** could be taken in the context of *"Here's to learning and knowledge"* or *"In respect of learning and knowledge"* etc.

**"For learning and knowledge"** could mean *"This gift is for learning and knowledge"*.

So, both versions are correct.